# Trying to work out the difference between two dates when strings

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to subtract two dates in php but the result is always returned as zero even though the data does have value and when I echo the dates they return correct but I am storing them in ACF in wordpress as strings in format.

But the data is the same ie date_joined

Date Joined value is  05/31/2016 06:33:27

Date Expiry Value is 06/14/2016 06:33:27

```
<?php

 $dateJoined = the_field('date_joined', $post_id );
 $expiredate = the_field('expiry_date', $post_id );

 //Convert them to timestamps.
 $difference=(int)abs((strtotime($expiredate) -   strtotime($dateJoined))/(60*60*24*30)); // 3 
?>
```

I am retrieving the values using

```
 $dateJoined = the_field('date_joined', $post_id );
 $expiredate = the_field('expiry_date', $post_id );
```

Which is the method which Advanced Custom Fields users to retrieve a custom field value but as you see its just returning a string

Comment: [Discover the power of the DateTime object side, Luke](https://3v4l.org/sG6fg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing the timestamp difference of roughly 15 days by the equivalent of 30 days and convert the result to integer. Thus the result is 0.

For most uses in code, the difference in seconds will suffice:

```
$difference = abs((strtotime($expiredate) - strtotime($dateJoined));
```

If you need to compare the value with other values in a coarser time unit, convert the compare values (by multiplying) to seconds.

Only convert your working value to a coarser unit for the purpose of presenting the result to the user ( eg. 'your password will expire in 3 days' ).

Comment: can you show the correct calcuation please and i will mark as the answer thanks

Comment: What unit of measure (seconds, days, months,...) do you want the difference to be associated with and to which precision? For starters, drop the division and the int cast to have seconds, which are best suited for use in the program imho. If you need  to compare with a coarser time unit, multiply the value of that unit to concert it into seconds. Only convert your working value to a coarser unit when presenting data to the user (eg. '... Will expire in 3 days').

Comment: Thanks for your kinda answer and yes will expire in 14 days they have 14 days to click a button or else it drops off but i am wanting to display it to the user

Comment: If you can provide a calualtion would be great sorry my mathmatics is not the best.

Comment: I complemented my answer.